# Is this retopology worth salvaging or should I start over from the beginning?

Tags: modeling, edges, retopology

I feel as though I have a lot of unnecessary vertices following through my model. I also have uneven amount of faces, so it's hard for me to close gaps. Some points are in the back and others a running through the arm. After finishing my retopology, I told myself I would go back and fix the mistakes I made. However, I feel overwhelmed and wonder if I that would be a waste of time compared to just starting over
[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's what my character looks like in Object mode.

Comment: it doesn't seem too bad, the butt is too messy though, make sure that the edge loops follow the shapes of the body

Comment: Thank you! The butt is my biggest issue right now. I have a lot of loops running down the side of the torso, and I would like to eventually connect the butt to the legs but I have 13 loops for that..

Comment: Have you tried selecting the rather large surface in those areas and subdivide?  Not sure it'll work but that's what I'd try.  Unfortunately, we often forget to backup our files before some major "surgery"!

Comment: I haven't yet! I can try. I backed up the file, luckily. I assume I would do edge loop reductions after the subdivision?